# Separate SOLR and banana

Tags: apache, nginx, solr, kibana

Currently I have SOLR and banana installed in my machine and both runs on the default jetty server.

Now, I need to move my SOLR to a separate webserver - probably apache and introduce a Nginx server between banana(jetty) and solr(apache), so that I can introduce a reverse proxy for security related issues.

Question:-

1. Which folder related to SOLR installation needs to be moved apache server?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot move Solr to Apache because it is a Java web application and therefore requires a servlet engine like Jetty, Tomcat.

You can move solr to a dedicated (tomcat / jetty / weblogic / ?) instance and eventually you may want to proxy with a front Apache